# how to establish a connection to a certain domain using domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, hosts-file

I have software that requires that I establish a connection to our server "SERVER01" which I am connecting via VPN to the domain "DOMAIN01"  The license will not permit me to use the following connection strings (which all work)

- "SERVER01.DOMAIN01.Local"
- "192.168.168.168"

Unfortunately, from my PC, I cannot just use the string "SERVER01" which is what the license is looking for.  What do I need to configure on my pc. to make it establish the connection correctly. 
Any help will be appreciated.

I have edited the hosts file on my own pc, and that solves the issue. however I would like to know what is the best setup so that I can minimise the issue across the organisation:

- is there a certain name that is better for the license key (ip, vs domain name, vs fully qualified vs some other variant)
- The problem is a lot easier when all hosts are on the same domain, my problem occurs when a pc is off the domain but connected to the VPN.

At the end of the day, I would like to ask the tool vendor to provide me with a license key for a server - and have the least impact to changes on the server

Comment: May be, you can add an entry for SERVER01 in your local pc's hosts file pointing to the server ip.

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a **minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Try including attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See *[How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/126632)* for further guidance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an entry for SERVER01 pointing to the server ip address in the local pc's hosts file as below:

```
192.168.168.168  SERVER01
```

In windows:

`%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`, which in most cases is:

`c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

In linux it is: `/etc/hosts`